# Epi Server 12.20.0 Publishing event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, content-management-system, episerver

I upgraded from Epi 12.8.0 to Epi 12.20.0. After the upgrade, I noticed that the publishing event is unable to capture the URL of the page that has been published. It worked fine in version 12.8.0, but not in the current version.

Is there a proper way to retrieve the page URL when publishing content using the IContent type object?

This is the code I'm using to get URL

This is initialization

```
public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
{

    _httpContextAccessor = context.Locate.Advanced.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    IConfiguration _configuration =  context.Locate.Advanced.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    _environment =  context.Locate.Advanced.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

    if (_contentEvents == null)
    {
        _contentEvents = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
    }
    _contentEvents.PublishedContent += PublishedContent;

}

private void PublishedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
    {
        
        IContent content = e.Content;
            var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();
        var pageUrl = urlResolver.GetUrl(content.ContentLink);
    }
```

In here this returns page url null

Comment: Please include the event handler code.

Comment: Most likely you are having an issue with authentication which has changed.  Most server are in the process of transition from Windows Authentication to OAUTH 2.0 because OAUTH 2.0 can be used for Windows, Linux, and MAC.

Comment: @TedNyberg Thanks,  I updated the question with the code lines

Comment: How are you attaching to the `Publishing` event? Could you include more of the code, for example the `IHostedService` or `IInitializableModule`?

Comment: @TedNyberg I updated the code, please see it. Also, I removed some unnecessary code from the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using constructor injection over the `ServiceLocator` class.

Are you positive the content has a template? In other words, are you able to browse to it? Otherwise `GetUrl()` will return `null`.

You're currently just looking for `IContent` (which may or may not be routable) so it might be better to do something like this for pages:

```
if (e.Content is PageData publishedPage)
{
   var url = _urlResolver.GetUrl(publishedPage);

   if (url != null)
   {
      // Do something with the URL
   }
   else {
      // Page has no URL, for example because there's no template for it
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that this PublishedContent() method calls each time when creating and publishing an event.   Actually, I'm using this with the epi server module so I don't have much Idea about how this is parsed as constructor injection . If you can suggest me any article about this, it would be great. However seems I think I can do something with this solution. I will let you know the results.  Thanks again